# How to allow '{' or '}' characters in a formatted python string

Tags: python-3.x, format-string

I need to print out a string similar to: `"Field1: {Bob} Field2: {value}"`
Where the 1st field is constant, but the second field is formatted from some variable.
I tried using a line like this:

```
field_str = "Field1: {Bob} Field2: {}".format(val)
```

But I get the error:

> ```
> KeyError: 'Bob'
> ```

I'm pretty sure this is because the '{' and '}' characters in the string are being interpreted as something that needs to be formatted even though I want the string to contain those values. This is part of a much larger string, so I would prefer to not manually concatenate the strings together, but I would be ok with somehow adding format characters or something to get it to ignore the values that are inside "{}" in the string.

Is there any way to indicate that a '{' or '}' character is not intended for formatting in a string?

Comment: Why aren't you using dictionary in this case? It will let you assign value to any key that is in `Field`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the double `{{}}` with python string formating f"...".

```
val = 2

field_str = f"Field1: {{Bob}} Field2: {val}"
print(field_str)
```

Output:

```
Field1: {Bob} Field2: 2
```

You may also pre-format the `Bob` value. For example

```
val = 2
field1 = '{Bob}'

field_str = f"Field1: {field1} Field2: {val}"
```